# I need 2 blocks for the same search index, one with email alert and one without

Tags: search

I use the [Search API saved searches](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_saved_searches) module to save my search and to get email alerts. I need one more block in the same page, which I need to use for just saving the current search. Can anyone help in this, or with suggesting any other module to get my second block for just saving searches?

Comment: Okay as far as understood based on what you explained is that you want a user to be able to save the search result and get an email alert for that saved search! you should explain why you want to separate these 2 actions from each other, since you can achieve both of them by using only 1 block of saved_search

Comment: some users may not be interested in getting email alerts and some users may be interested in getting mail alerts. So just to give them a choice i need two blocks,one with mail alert and one without.

Comment: you shouldn't really do that for your need! since every configuration of the module itslef applies to the block, what I suggest instead is to try to write a custom module, add a checkbox like "signup for mail alerts" in the saved search block and trigger the alert based on that checkbox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

setting negative value for notify interval will just save the search, without sending any mail alert in search_api_saved_search module.